# How to proxy a jsonp call in service worker

Tags: javascript, jsonp, service-worker, progressive-web-apps, offline-caching

My site fetches some user-based data from another site through a jsonp call
how can I proxy these request for offline use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JSONP pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) involves adding a `<script>` element to your page, the source of which will invoke a callback that exposes the data from the remote URL to your page.

From the service worker's perspective, this the addition of a `<script>` will trigger a `fetch` event, with the `event.request.destination` set to `'script'`. Additionally, the `event.request.url` will be set to the full URL of the JSONP script resource. You could use a combination of one or both of those facts to tell your service worker's `fetch` handler to do something special when it encounters a JSONP request:

```
self.addEventListener('fetch', (event) => {
  if (event.request.destinaton = 'script' &&
      event.request.url.startsWith('https://example.com')) {
    // Your caching strategy goes here.
    // E.g. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/instant-and-offline/offline-cookbook#network-falling-back-to-cache
  }
});
```

Comment: The problem is not how to recognize the jsonp request.
We can't use fetch to make jsonp requset in service worker. instead of that should use importScripts but with this soloution I can't proxy the base request.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't use `fetch(event.request)` inside your `fetch` event handler to get the `Response` corresponding to the `<script>` resource.

Comment: Because its from different domain and `CORS` isn't available

Comment: Your request can use `mode: 'no-cors'`. In fact, if you're intercepting an incoming `FetchEvent` in a service worker that originates from a `<script>` tag on your page, `event.request.mode` should already be set to `'no-cors'`. The opaque response you get back can still be cached and used to respond when offline.